# Making use of selected or clicked cell without VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2007, cell

A tricky one, I assume. However, is there a way to make use of a selected or clicked cell in Excel somehow without the need for VBA? 
(I know how to do it with VBA, but macros are macros, but if you want to give workbooks to people...)

For instance, I would like to make some of the content in the freezed section to be dependent on where in the sheet someone is. It would be optimal, if the selected cell/row would be trigger enough.
It would be also okay, if clicking a cell (e.g. a link navigating in the sheet) would trigger the conent to change. Hence, a solution would be to make a hyperlink change a value in some cell somewhere. I know, this is a different question, but it should be all accomplishing the same goal of the line on top ;-)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1. You **cannot change values or display** of another cell with formula or functions.
2. The **hyperlink** will send you to another location but **won't change the freezed part**, except if you only freeze rows and the hyperlink send you to a further column. But you will have then to really think about your layout very precisely. Moreover, the user will even less understand what happens unless you can design a great UI (but Excel may not be the best tool though).

Some tips:

1. Use hyperlinks but on **differents sheets**
2. Use "transparent" macros (without big buttons but rather **event vba** as you pointed out)

Sorry i don't have a magical solution.